# min() function in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, min, iterable

It seems that the inbuilt `min()` function for determining the minimum value in a given iterable. I have this line of code:

```
result = min(cost+futureCost(newState) \
                for action, newState, cost in problem.succAndCost(state))
```

where `newState` is of integer type and the function `futureCost()` returns an integer. How the enclosed parameters form an iterable in this case?

Comment: I don't see a question here. What question do you want to ask us?

Comment: What is the question here

Comment: I'm sorry, i just edited my question.

Comment: how `cost+futureCost(newState) \
                for action, newState, cost in problem.succAndCost(state)` forms an iterable is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a generator expression. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289